Issues to manage a complex loop about Number Walls (Mathologer video) and tips for a faster coding
I'm new in Julia. I'm trying to code an algorithm about the building of Number Walls (there's a video of Mathologer talking about them). I wrote a code but I don't know how to make it work since:

the most of the time it doesn't give me the right output
I did some changes in the past resulting in forever loops that can't be stopped.

I program using VS Code, my Computer is a HP with Windows. My Julia program is updated.
using Plotly, PlotlyJS
using Statistics, ProgressMeter
PlotlyJS.plotlyjs()  #gives me error
plotlyjs()  #gives me error too

width = 128
height = 128

data = zeros(Float32, width, height)

data[data .== 0] .=NaN

data[1,:] = zeros(Int, width)
data[2,:] = ones(Int, width)

seqq = [0, 1, 1, 0]
w = 0
while w <13
    seqq2 = .-1 .* seqq .+ 1
    seqq = vcat(seqq,seqq2)
    w += 1
end

data[3,:]= seqq[1:width]

riempi_matrice_2 = function()

    total_steps = (width - 3) * (width - 2)
    p = Progress(total_steps)

    for i in 3 : (width-1)
        for j in 2:(width-1)
            if !isnan(data[i, j-1]) 
                if data[i,j] != 0
                    if data[i-1, j] != 0 

                        data[i+1, j] = data[i, j]^2 - data[i, j-1] * data[i, j+1] / data[i-1, j]

                    elseif data[i-1,j] == 0 && data[i-2,j] != 0 #&& j-2>0 && j+2 <= 2000 

                        if j-2>0 && j+2 <= width
                            data[i+1, j] = (data[i-1,j-1]^2*data[i-1,j+2]+data[i-1,j+1]^2*data[i-1,j-2]-data[i-3,j]*data[i,j]^2)/data[i-2,j]^2
                        end

                    elseif data[i-1,j] == 0 && data[i-2,j] == 0 #j-2>0 && j+2 <= 2000 &&

                        l_lato_finestra = 0
                        posiz_sul_lato_dal_fondo = 1

                        for n in 1:(i-2)
                            if data[i-n,j] == 0
                                l_lato_finestra +=1
                                n += 1
                            else
                                break
                            end
                        end

                        for n in 1:(i-2)
                            if data[i-1,j+n] == 0
                                posiz_sul_lato_dal_fondo +=1
                                n += 1
                            else
                                break
                            end
                        end

                        lato_sinistro = j+posiz_sul_lato_dal_fondo-l_lato_finestra-1

                        rapp_geom_up = data[i-l_lato_finestra-1,j+1]/data[i-l_lato_finestra-1,j]
                        rapp_geom_left = data[i-1, lato_sinistro]/data[i-2,lato_sinistro]
                        rapp_geom_right = data[i-2, j + posiz_sul_lato_dal_fondo]/data[i-1, j + posiz_sul_lato_dal_fondo]

                        rapp_geom_down = (-1)^l_lato_finestra * rapp_geom_left * rapp_geom_right / rapp_geom_up

                        data[i+1,j]= (data[i-l_lato_finestra-2,j]/data[i-l_lato_finestra-1,j]*rapp_geom_left+
                        (-1)^posiz_sul_lato_dal_fondo*data[i-l_lato_finestra+posiz_sul_lato_dal_fondo,lato_sinistro-1]/data[i-l_lato_finestra+posiz_sul_lato_dal_fondo,lato_sinistro]*rapp_geom_up-
                        (-1)^posiz_sul_lato_dal_fondo*data[i-posiz_sul_lato_dal_fondo,j+posiz_sul_lato_dal_fondo]/data[i-posiz_sul_lato_dal_fondo,j+posiz_sul_lato_dal_fondo]*rapp_geom_down)*
                        data[i,j]/rapp_geom_right

                    end
                
                else # data[i,j] ==0
                    if  data[i-1,j] != 0 

                        data[i+1, j] = data[i, j]^2 - data[i, j-1] * data[i, j+1] / data[i-1, j]

                    else  #data[i-1,j] == 0

                        if data[i-2,j] != 0

                            if j-2>0 && j+2 <= width
                                data[i+1, j] = (data[i-1,j-1]^2*data[i-1,j+2]+data[i-1,j+1]^2*data[i-1,j-2]-data[i-3,j]*data[i,j]^2)/data[i-2,j]^2
                            end

                        else #data[i-2,j] == 0

                            if data[i+1,j-1] == 0

                                data[i+1,j] = 0

                            else #data[i+1,j-1] != 0

                                l_lato_finestra = 0
                                posiz_sul_lato_dal_fondo = 1

                                for n in 1:(i-2)
                                    if data[i-n,j] == 0
                                        l_lato_finestra += 1
                                        n += 1
                                    else
                                        break
                                    end
                                end

                                for n in 1:(i-2)
                                    if data[i-1,j+n] == 0
                                        posiz_sul_lato_dal_fondo += 1
                                        n += 1
                                    else
                                        break
                                    end
                                end

                                lato_sinistro = j+posiz_sul_lato_dal_fondo-l_lato_finestra-1

                                rapp_geom_up = data[i-l_lato_finestra,j+1]/data[i-l_lato_finestra,j]
                                rapp_geom_left = data[i-1, lato_sinistro]/data[i-2,lato_sinistro]
                                rapp_geom_right = data[i-2, j + posiz_sul_lato_dal_fondo]/data[i-1, j + posiz_sul_lato_dal_fondo]

                                rapp_geom_down = (-1)^l_lato_finestra * rapp_geom_left * rapp_geom_right / rapp_geom_up

                                data[i+1,j]=data[i+1,j-1]/rapp_geom_down
                            end
                        end                        
                    end
                end
            end
            next!(p)
        end
    end
end


riempi_matrice_2()



color_matrix = [isodd(abs(data[i,j])) ? "rgb(0, 0, 255)" : (iseven(abs(data[i,j])) ? "rgb(255, 0, 0)" : (isnan(data[i,j]) ? "rgb(0,0,0)" : "rgb(255,255,255)")) for i in 1:height, j in 1:width]


heatmap_plotly = PlotlyJS.plot(PlotlyJS.heatmap(
    z = data[1:30,1:60],
    color = color_matrix
))

Here the code creates a NxN matrix of Nan. I fill the first 3 rows with desired numbers and then, thanks to the function 'riempi_matrice_2()' it should fill the remaining matrix. I should eventually obtain a matrix I can display with plotly... but until now it never happened properly.
